# Unhappy to be a developer / work in an office

Tags: resignation, stress

I am unenthusiastic working as a developer in an office. I don't earn a high income now but I know that with experience I can earn a good income in the future but what do I do now that I am so unhappy everyday?

I prefer to be an Uber driver, which doesn't pay much and wages are stagnant (No increment as you get more experience). So definitely I have this conflict in my mind.

I am in the office now and the thing at the back of my mind everyday is I want to go home, I don't want to be here.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an answerable question here.

Comment: Being an Uber driver isn't a job. For most drivers it's a gimmick that will barely break even after costs are taken into consideration. For the company it's a way to circumvent employment and wage laws. That aside, career advice or general rants that don't contain a real question aren't answerable on this site and therefore off-topic.

Comment: I had to look up 'Uber driver'

Comment: Of all possible career moves, that must be one of the worst.

Comment: "I know that with experience I can earn a good income in the future" - if you quit now or spend too many days wishing you were somewhere else, you will probably not get the experience you know you need. Find whatever motivation you need to do what you have to do.

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/2016-02-24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being in the situation where you're the person saying "I'm unhappy with my job" can happen to any of us. It happens. The job might not be what you expected. Or, the job itself may be okay. If you've reached the point where you have acknowledged that you cannot move ahead with the job then you need to know and you have to figure out what to do next.

Don't just quit your job. You don't want to resign in haste and repent in leisure if you can't find another job fast. Begin by considering options for making the job work. Is there anything you could be doing different to be happier at work? Could you ask for a transfer or a shift change? Is there anything that would make a difference and convince you to stay?

Consider the alternatives, before you make a decision to leave. Finding a new job isn't always easy, if there's a fix, it's worth pursuing.

Definitely there are ways to be happy and enthusiastic at workplace.

1. **Define your goals** and what you need to do to achieve them – I know you've heard it before, but if you haven't done it yet, sit down and write down your most important life goals. Then put a plan together to accomplish them.
2. **Get organized** – Get a system together that will squeeze the most productivity out of each day and stick to it. Don’t procrastinate or get distracted. Keep focused on the task at hand, and you will turn every workday into a success.
3. **Draw strength from the positive** – Remember the times in your life when you were enthusiastic. Feed off those positive feelings. Learn from the times you failed, but focus and draw inspiration from your successes.